# Openpyxl: Manipulation of cell values

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, openpyxl

I'm trying to pull cell values from an excel sheet, do math with them, and write the output to a new sheet. I keep getting an ErrorType. I've run the code successfully before, but just added this aspect of it, thus code has been distilled to below:

```
import openpyxl

#set up ws from file, and ws_out write to new file

def get_data():
    first = 0
    second = 0
    for x in range (1, 1000):
        if ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value == 'string':
            for y in range (1, 10):            #Only need next ten rows after 'string'

                ws_out.cell(row=y, column=1).value = ws.cell(row=x+y, column=1).value

                second = first                             #displaces first -> second
                first = ws.cell(row=x+y, column=1).value/100     #new value for first
                difference = first - second

                ws_out.cell(row=x+y+1, column=1).value = difference    #add to output
            break
```

Throws a TypeError message:

> first = ws.cell(row=x+y, column=1).value)/100
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

I assume this is referring to the ws.cell value and 100, respectively, so I've also tried:

```
first = int(ws.cell(row=x, column=1))/100 #also tried with float
```

Which raises:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number

I've confirmed that every cell in the column is made up of numbers only. Additionally, openpyxl's cell.data_type returns 'n' (presumably for number as far as I can tell by the documentation).

I've also tested more simple math, and have the same error.

All of my searching seems to point to openpyxl normally behaving like this. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply a limitation of the module? If so, are there any programmatic workarounds?

As a bonus, advice on writing code more succinctly would be much appreciated. I'm just beginning, and feel there must be a cleaner way to write an ideas like this.

Python 3.3, openpyxl-1.6.2, Windows 7

---

**Summary**

cfi's answer helped me figure it out, although I used a slightly different workaround. On inspection of the originating file, there was one empty cell (which I had missed earlier). Since I will be re-using this code later on columns with more sporadic empty cells, I used:

```
if ws.cell(row=x+r, column=40).data_type == 'n':
    second = first                             #displaces first -> second
    first = ws.cell(row=x+y, column=1).value/100     #new value for first
    difference = first - second

    ws_out.cell(row=x+y+1, column=1).value = difference    #add to output
```

Thus, if a specified cell was empty, it was ignored and skipped.

Comment: Please always post the code that matches the quoted error. `row=x+r` refers to a variable `r` that does not exist in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you 100% sure (=have verified) that all the cells you are accessing actually hold a value? (Edit: Do a `print("dbg> cell value of {}, {} is {}".format(row, 1, ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value))` to verify content)

Instead of going through a fixed range(1,1000) I'd recomment to use openpyxl introspection methods to iterate over existing rows. E.g.:

```
wb=load_workbook(inputfile)
    for ws in wb.worksheets:
        for row in ws.rows:
            for cell in row:  value = cell.value
```

When getting the values do not forget to extract the `.value` attribute:

```
first = ws.cell(row=x+y, column=1).value/100    #new value for first
```

As a general note: `x`, and `y` are useful variable names for 2D coordinates. Don't use them both for rows. It will mislead others who have to read the code. Instead of `x` you could use `start_row` or `row_offset` or something similar. Instead of `y` you could just use `row` and you could let it start with the first index being the `start_row+1`.

Some example code (untested):

```
def get_data():
    first = 0
    second = 0
    for start_row in range (1, ws.rows):
        if ws.cell(row=start_row, column=1).value == 'string':
            for row in range (start_row+1, start_row+10):

                ws_out.cell(row=start_row, column=1).value = ws.cell(row=row, column=1)

                second = first
                first = ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value/100
                difference = first - second

                ws_out.cell(row=row+1, column=1).value = difference
            break
```

Now with this code I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Is the `break` indented correctly? If yes, the first time you are matching `string`, the outer loop will be quit by the `break`. Then, what is the point of the variables `first` and `second`?

Edit: Also ensure that your reading from **and** writing into `cell().value` not just `cell()`.

Comment: The `break` is indented correctly, as I'm only looking for the first instance of `string` to initiate the next `if` statement. `First` and `Second` look at other variables with a specific relation to `string` and subtract one from the other. (Specifically, they're time points: Time 2 subtracted from Time 1 for a difference, with Time 1 becoming the value for Time 2 for the next row. Time used to calculate an velocity for `string`.)  I like your idea of renaming some of the variables, which I will do. Many thanks

Comment: @Jonathan: Added that you could `print()` values before using them for computation to verify content. Secondly ensure you wrinte into `cell.value`, not just `cell`. Edited my code example accordingly. - Ah I just see you edited your Q already..